# How to present a viewcontroller from a notification observer selectors

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, notifications

I am implementing session inactivity for my app like when app is not been touched for 30 seconds, it should show an another screen on top of current screen with option either to logout or continue. I have implemented the feature to detect touch and able to create notification once application is not touched. If i put NSLog when notification observer is called, everything is doing good. But i am not sure how to show the screen.

Like i put a notification in my rootviewController class and in the ApplicationDidTimeout method, i tried to performSegueWithIdentifier which doesn't work. I don't get the view. So, i tried the code written below , it loads the view But i want the view in Formsheet so that i can come on top of other view.

Can someone please help me with this so that i can show up sessionView on top of anyView when session Timeouts

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];    

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidTimeout:) name:@"ApplicationDidTimeout" object:nil];
}

- (void) applicationDidTimeout:(NSNotification *) notif
{
    NSLog(@"I m here");
    BCDSessionInactivityViewController *sessionView=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InactivityViewController"];
     [[self topViewController] presentViewController:sessionView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Your first task should be to learn to format a Stack Overflow question properly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But i want the view in Formsheet

```
BCDSessionInactivityViewController *sessionView=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"InactivityViewController"];
sessionView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[[self topViewController] presentViewController:sessionView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks matt. It was quick help. And, i also would take care of formatting which asking question